# Sort downloads from dropdown

Tags: taxonomy-terms, nodes

i have alot of car drawings that i want to upload to my website and make downloadable .. the thing is that i want to have a dropdown menu, 1 with manufacture, 1 with model, and 1 with year .. from there you must be able to find your specific car from the drop down menu ..

i know i need to use taxonomy but thats about it, i dont really know how to implement it in views, or what content type i must create, if its 1 for each car model or 1 for each manufacture ..

all ideas are appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need to create one content type of type car. The content type will have different fields such as manufacturer (which will be a term field),  brand(Will also be a term field), date manufactured (It can be a term field or a dropdown).

Then you go ahead and create a view of type display page according to your specification.

**UPDATE**

Add the three fields (manufacturer, type and brand) to the sort criteria and expose them.

See screenshot below

[image]

For the download link use the  [download file module](https://drupal.org/project/download_file) with your car content type

Comment: Hi there. thanks for your fast reply :) - im sorry if i did not explain it well , i dont want the link to be in the menu .. i want drop down boxes .. if you choose manifacture it shows all models, if you choose model it shows you year, if you choose year it shows you a download link for that specific model.. 

I beleive you are right, do you have any alternative suggestion? i would really appreciate it :)

Comment: Thank you very much, i am working with it at, at this very moment .. and yes this seems to be the solution i am looking for. i now only have a few questions - 1. i dont want a sort by drop down, i want the drop down to show the car, model, and year . sort is like sorting what is already displayed .. can i filter it out so it shows nothing untill you chose what car you want?

Comment: In that case add the fields to the filter criteria and expose them

Answer (score 1):

For generating drop-down menus we have a module [nice_menu](https://drupal.org/project/nice_menus) refer to the module go through it readme.txt for better understanding .

and use command

"drush dl nice_menu"

for the most compatible version

Comment: Hi there, thank you as well :) i cant use Drush or Git because of my host "One.com" does not allow SSH directly to server :/

Answer (score 1):

Use OM Menu. This is a better solution I have already implemented this in one of my project. This will give you block for menu as drop down. Please check OM menu

Answer (score 1):

1. For creating drop down menus for selecting the appropriate car based on some properties ,you may use HIERARCHICAL SELECT module.
2. [hierarchical select module](https://drupal.org/project/hierarchical_select) ,hope this may be of some help .